# define predicate prolog by requirements

Tags: prolog

I have to define a predicate p(X, Y), where Y = f(X) where

[image]

How could I define the predicate, according to this requirements?

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost the same way it's written there, three cases for Y's value given different X conditions:

```
f(X, Y) :- X < 4,             Y is X ^ 2 - 1.
f(X, Y) :- X >= 4, X =< 6,    Y is sqrt(X) + 1.
f(X, Y) :- X > 6,             Y is 9 - X.
```

or the middle case

```
f(X, Y) :- between(4, 6, X),  Y is sqrt(X) + 1.
```

which I had originally and find more readable, but changes the behaviour for that case, which is a tradeoff.

Then:

```
:- f(3, Y).
Y = 8
```

( [zcompare/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=zcompare/3) hints at a way to get rid of the choice points without using cut `!`, but only if you restrict to integers ).

Comment: `#<` yet also `>`?

Comment: @false just ordinary `<`, thanks;  fixed.

Comment: And, `f(0+3,R)` succeeds, but `f(0+4, R)` produces an error.

Comment: @false Is that an important usecase? Python has a nice `lower <= X <= upper` combined bound test with symbols. I think it's underappreciated.

Comment: Do you want to confine yourself to "important usecases" only? Or do you want to produce consistent definitions?

Comment: @false I don't know if I want to produce consistent definitions; `between()` is so much more readable than the alternative that if `f(0+4, R)` is unimportant and being brought up as a nitpick then I would prefer readable and inconsistent. If `f(0+4, R)`  approximates something common and important, it's probably better consistent but uglier. If there were `below(4, X)` and `above(6, X)` builtins I might make it consistent the other way; carefully reading `X>`, `>X`, `X<`, `<X`, `X>=`, `>=X`, `X=<`, `=<X` to make sure it's right is not something I enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

Another way that doesn't leave choice points behind...

```
f(X,Y) :- X  < 4 -> Y is X^2 - 1     ;
          X =< 6 -> Y is sqrt(X) + 1 ;
                    Y is 9 - X       .
```

Comment: Huh, I would have guessed `;` would leave a choicepoint especially since `X=2` is both `<4` and `=< 6`. That's much neater.